# C++ Boost ASIO async_send_to memory leak

Tags: c++, memory, memory-leaks, boost-asio

I am currently working on a UDP socket client. I am currently noticing a memory leak and I've tried several things in hopes to squash it, but it still prevails. In my main, I have a `char*` that has been `malloc`'d. I then call the below function to send the data:

```
void Send(const char* data, const int size) {
    Socket.async_send_to(boost::asio::buffer(data, size), Endpoint, boost::bind(&MulticastSender::HandleSendTo, this, boost::asio::placeholders::error));   
}
```

If I run this code, it will always leak memory. However, if I comment out the `async_send_to` call, the memory stays consistent.
I have tried several variations(see below) on this, but they all only appear to speed up the memory leak.

A couple notes, there is a chance that the `char*` that gets passed to Send may get `free`'d before the call completes. However, in my variations, I have taken precaution to do handle that.

**Variation 1:**

```
void Send(const char* data, const int size) {
    char* buf = (char*)malloc(size);
    memcpy(buf, data, size);
    Socket.async_send_to(boost::asio::buffer(buf, size), Endpoint, boost::bind(&MulticastSender::HandleSendTo, this, boost::asio::placeholders::error, buf));   
}

void HandleSendTo(const boost::system::error_code& ec, const char* buf) {
    free(buf);
}
```

**Variation 2:**

```
class MulticastSender {
    char* Buffer;

    public:
    void Send(const char* data, const int size) {
        Buffer = (char*)malloc(size);
        memcpy(Buffer, data, size);
        Socket.async_send_to(boost::asio::buffer(Buffer, size), Endpoint, boost::bind(&MulticastSender::HandleSendTo, this, boost::asio::placeholders::error));
    }

    void HandleSendTo(const boost::system::error_code& ec) {
        free(Buffer);
    }
}
```

However, both variations seem to only speed up the memory leak. I have also tried removing the `async_send_to` and just calling `boost::asio::buffer(data, size)`, but as has been explained in other questions, the buffer does not own the memory and thus it is up to the user to safely manage it. Any thoughts on what could be causing this issue and how to resolve it?

**EDIT 1:**

As suggested in the comments, I have preallocated a single buffer (for test purposes) and I am never deallocating it, however, the memory leak still persists.

```
class MulticastSender {
    char* Buffer;
    const int MaxSize = 16384;

    public:
    MulticastSender() {
        Buffer = (char*)malloc(MaxSize);
    }

    void Send(const char* data, const int size) {
        memcpy(Buffer, data, size);
        Socket.async_send_to(boost::asio::buffer(Buffer, size), Endpoint, boost::bind(&MulticastSender::HandleSendTo, this, boost::asio::placeholders::error));
    }

    void HandleSendTo(const boost::system::error_code& ec) {

    }
}
```

**EDIT 2:**
As requested here is an MCVE of the problem. In making this I have also observed an interesting behavior that I will explain below.

```
#include <string>
#include <iostream>
#include <functional>
#include <thread>

#include <boost/asio.hpp>
#include <boost/bind.hpp>

class MulticastSender {
private:
    boost::asio::io_service IOService;
    const unsigned short Port;
    const boost::asio::ip::address Address;
    boost::asio::ip::udp::endpoint Endpoint;
    boost::asio::ip::udp::socket Socket;
    boost::asio::streambuf Buffer;

    void HandleSendTo(const boost::system::error_code& ec) {
        if(ec) {
            std::cerr << "Error writing data to socket: " << ec.message() << '\n';
        }
    }

    void Run() {
        IOService.run();
    }

public:
    MulticastSender(const std::string& address,
                    const std::string& multicastaddress,
                    const unsigned short port) : Address(boost::asio::ip::address::from_string(address)),
                                                 Port(port),
                                                 Endpoint(Address, port),
                                                 Socket(IOService, Endpoint.protocol()) {
        std::thread runthread(&MulticastSender::Run, this);
        runthread.detach();
    }

    void Send(const char* data, const int size) {
        std::ostreambuf_iterator<char> out(&Buffer);
        std::copy(data, data + size, out);
        Socket.async_send_to(Buffer.data(), Endpoint, boost::bind(&MulticastSender::HandleSendTo, this, boost::asio::placeholders::error));
    }
};

const int SIZE = 8192;

int main() {
    MulticastSender sender("127.0.0.1", "239.255.0.0", 30000);
    while(true) {
        char* data = (char*)malloc(SIZE);
        std::memset(data, 0, SIZE);
        sender.Send(data, SIZE);
        usleep(250);
        free(data);
    }
}
```

The above code still produces a memory leak. I should mention that I am running this on `CentOS 6.6 with kernel Linux dev 2.6.32-504.el6.x86_64` and running `Boost 1.55.0`. I am observing this simply by watching the process in `top`.

**However**, if I simply move the creation of the `MulticastSender` into the `while` loop, I no longer observe the memory leak. I am concerned about the speed of the application though, so this is not a valid option.

Comment: Preallocate the send buffer and never release it. This way you will avoid problems with heap and improve your apps stability. Use a buffer pool to quickly get a free buffer when needed. Since you're using UDP there's a maximum packet size you'll never exceed, so you can preallocate, say, a pool of 10 buffers of that maximum size and use them to send.

Comment: @berkus I have tried a simplistic version of your suggestion and placed an example above. The comment about stability is something I can definitely get behind, but the memory leak still seems to occur.

Comment: Can you please provide a [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) that one can verify with a memory-analysis tool, such as Valgrind?  Also, can you explain how the memory-leaks are being detected?

Comment: @TannerSansbury I have added an MCVE as well as my observations as an edit.

Comment: Thank you for the MCVE.  While `top` can be used to observe memory growth, it does not necessarily imply a memory-leak.  I would _strongly_ suggest using memory-analysis tools to detect memory-leaks and benchmark tools for performance.  Also, I would be hesitant on any premature optimizations, particularly when the program may end up I/O bound.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Memory is not leaking, as there is still a handle to the allocated memory.  However, there will be continual growth because:

- The `io_service` is not running because [`run()`](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_59_0/doc/html/boost_asio/reference/io_service/run/overload1.html) is returning as there is no work.  This results in completion handlers being allocated, queued into the `io_service`, but neither executed nor freed.  Additionally, any cleanup that is expected to occur within the completion handler is not occurring.  It is worth noting that during the destruction of the `io_service`, completion handlers will be destroyed and not invoked; hence, one cannot depend on only performing cleanup within the execution of the completion handler.  For more details as to when `io_service::run()` blocks or unblocks, consider reading [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15568100/) question.
- The `streambuf`'s input sequence is never being consumed.  Each iteration in the main loop will append to the `streambuf`, which will then send the prior message content and the newly appended data.  See [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31960010/boost-asio-streambuf/31992879) answer for more details on the overall usage of `streambuf`.

A few other points:

- The program fails to meet a requirement of [`async_send_to()`](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_59_0/doc/html/boost_asio/reference/basic_datagram_socket/async_send_to/overload1.html), where ownership of the underlying buffer memory is retained by the caller, who must guarantee that it remains valid until the handler is called.  In this case, when copying into the `streambuf` via the `ostreambuf_iterator`, the `streambuf`'s input sequence is modified and invalidates the buffer returned from [`streambuf.data()`](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_59_0/doc/html/boost_asio/reference/basic_streambuf/data.html).
- During shutdown, some form of synchronization will need to occur against threads that are running the `io_service`.  Otherwise, undefined behavior may be invoked.

---

To resolve these issues, consider:

- Using [`boost::asio::io_service::work`](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_59_0/doc/html/boost_asio/reference/io_service__work.html) to ensure that the `io_service` object's `run()` does not exit when there is no work remaining.
- Passing ownership of the memory to the completion handler via `std::shared_ptr` or another class that will manage the memory via [resource acquisition is initialization](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Resource_Acquisition_Is_Initialization) (RAII) idiom.  This will allow for proper cleanup and meet the requirement's of the buffer validity for `async_send_to()`.
- Not detaching and joining upon the worker thread.

Here is a complete example based on the original that [demonstrates](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/8a3639274a49e27a) these changes:

```cpp
#include <string>
#include <iostream>
#include <thread>
#include <boost/asio.hpp>

class multicast_sender
{
public:

  multicast_sender(
    const std::string& address,
    const std::string& multicast_address,
    const unsigned short multicast_port)
  : work_(io_service_),
    multicast_endpoint_(
      boost::asio::ip::address::from_string(multicast_address),
      multicast_port),
    socket_(io_service_, boost::asio::ip::udp::endpoint(
      boost::asio::ip::address::from_string(address),
      0 /* any port */))
  {
    // Start running the io_service.  The work_ object will keep
    // io_service::run() from returning even if there is no real work
    // queued into the io_service.
    auto self = this;
    work_thread_ = std::thread([self]()
      {
        self->io_service_.run();
      });
  }

  ~multicast_sender()
  {
    // Explicitly stop the io_service.  Queued handlers will not be ran.
    io_service_.stop();

    // Synchronize with the work thread.
    work_thread_.join();
  }

  void send(const char* data, const int size)
  {
    // Caller may delete before the async operation finishes, so copy the
    // buffer and associate it to the completion handler's lifetime.  Note
    // that the completion may not run in the event the io_servie is
    // destroyed, but the the completion handler will be, so managing via
    // a RAII object (std::shared_ptr) is ideal.
    auto buffer = std::make_shared<std::string>(data, size);
    socket_.async_send_to(boost::asio::buffer(*buffer), multicast_endpoint_,
      [buffer](
        const boost::system::error_code& error,
        std::size_t bytes_transferred)
      {
        std::cout << "Wrote " << bytes_transferred << " bytes with " <<
                     error.message() << std::endl;
      });
  }

private:
  boost::asio::io_service io_service_;
  boost::asio::io_service::work work_;
  boost::asio::ip::udp::endpoint multicast_endpoint_;
  boost::asio::ip::udp::socket socket_;
  std::thread work_thread_;

};

const int SIZE = 8192;

int main()
{
  multicast_sender sender("127.0.0.1", "239.255.0.0", 30000);
  char* data = (char*) malloc(SIZE);
  std::memset(data, 0, SIZE);
  sender.send(data, SIZE);
  free(data);

  // Give some time to allow for the async operation to complete 
  // before shutting down the io_service.
  std::this_thread::sleep_for(std::chrono::seconds(2));
}
```

Output:

```cpp
Wrote 8192 bytes with Success
```

Comment: Thanks so much for this. I was pretty fixated on the assumption that it was a leak and failed to look into my usage of the boost libraries. I certainly appreciate the detailed response, there's a lot of knowledge in this post that is great to have summed up in this manner.

Comment: @Tsy My pleasure.  Thank you for the MCVE!  It was absolutely essential in being able to identify the problem.

Answer (score 1):

The class variation looks better, and you can use `boost::asio::streambuf` as a buffer for network io (it doesn't leak and doesn't need much maintenance).

```cpp
// The send function
void
send(char const* data, size_t size)
{
    std::ostreambuf_iterator<char> out(&buffer_);
    std::copy(data, data + size, out);

    socket.async_send_to(buffer_, endpoint, 
            std::bind( &multicast_sender, 
                    this, std::placeholders::_1 ));
}
```

Moving the socket and endpoint inside the class would be a good idea. Also you should bear in mind that the async operation can finish when your object goes out of scope. I would recommend using `enable_shared_from_this` (boost or std flavours) and pass `shared_from_this()` instead of `this` to the bind function.
The whole solution would look like this:

```cpp
#include <boost/asio.hpp>

class multicast_sender : 
        public std::enable_shared_from_this<multicast_sender> {
    using boost::asio::ip::udp;
    udp::socket socket_;
    udp::endpoint endpoint_;
    boost::asio::streambuf buffer_;
public:
    multicast_sender(boost::asio::io_service& io_service, short port, 
            udp::endpoint const& remote) : 
        socket_(io_service, udp::endpoint(udp::v4(), port)), 
        endpoint_(remote)
    {
    }
    void
    send(char const* data, size_t size)
    {
        std::ostreambuf_iterator<char> out(&buffer_);
        std::copy(data, data + size, out);

        socket_.async_send_to(buffer_, endpoint_, 
                std::bind( &multicast_sender, 
                        shared_from_this(), std::placeholders::_1 ));
    }

    void
    handle_send(boost::system::error_code const& ec)
    {
    }
};
```

**EDIT**
And as far as you don't have to do anything in the write handler, you can use a lambda (requires C++11) as a completion callback

```cpp
// The send function
void
send(char const* data, size_t size)
{
    std::ostreambuf_iterator<char> out(&buffer_);
    std::copy(data, data + size, out);

    socket.async_send_to(buffer_, endpoint, 
            [](boost::system::error_code const& ec){
                std::cerr << "Error sending :" << ec.message() << "\n";
            });
}
```

Comment: Using the `streambuf` feels awkward to me when dealing with a message based protocol.  Regardless, I do want to note that the `streambuf` cannot be directly passed to the `async_send_to()` operation, as it expects a type fulfilling the `ConstBufferSequence` type requirement.  While one could use `streambuf.data()` and explicitly provide the message size to maintain message boundaries, the completion handler would need to `consume()` the input sequence and guarantee that `send()` is not invoked again until the input sequence is consumed to avoid violating a requirement of `async_send_to()`.