# boost::asio::streambuf - how to reuse buffer?

Tags: c++, boost, boost-asio

I'm implementing TCP server that uses both asio socket.async_read() and boost::asio::async_read_until() methods for asynchronous reading data from socket. Both use the same handler for reading data from boost::asio::streambuf.

The handler that perfectly works invoked via async_read() :

```
void handle_read(const boost::system::error_code& ec, std::size_t ytes_transferred) )
{
    m_request_buffer.commit(bytes_transferred);
    boost::asio::streambuf::const_buffers_type rq_buf_data = m_request_buffer.data();
    std::vector<uint8_t> dataBytes(boost::asio::buffers_begin(rq_buf_data), boost::asio::buffers_begin(rq_buf_data) + bytes_transferred);

    //process data here

    m_request_buffer.consume(bytes_transferred);
    bytes_transferred = 0;
}
```

My server depending on processing of data may shutdown connection or continue reading via the same socket.

But, if handle_read() is called from the 2-nd boost::asi::async_read_until() call, I'm getting a number of zero's in dataBytes and then valid data goes.

I tried a simple test-case and found out that after writing data to streambuf, and commit() + consume() the data in streambuf still keeps previous buffer.

So, is there any way to clear data in boost::asio::streambuf and reuse it in boost::asio::async_read_until() ?

[Live Coliru](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/aab889f4789d1c71)

If compiled with USE_STREAM=1, the live example works fine. But what std::istream does different comparing with buffer consume() ?

Answer (score 11):

When using Boost.Asio operations that operate on `streambuf` or stream objects that use a `streambuf`, such as `std::ostream` and `std::istream`, the underlying input and output sequences will be properly managed.  If a buffer is provided to an operation instead, such as passing passing `prepare()` to a read operation or `data()` to a write operation, then one must explicitly handle the `commit()` and `consume()`.

The issue in the example is that it violates the API contract, causing uninitialized memory to be committed to the input sequence.  The [`commit()`](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_61_0/doc/html/boost_asio/reference/basic_streambuf/commit.html) documentation states:

> Requires a preceding call `prepare(x)` where `x >= n`, and no intervening operations that modify the input or output sequence.

The use of the `std::ostream` between the `prepare()` and `commit()` violates this contract, as it will modify the input sequence:

```cpp
// Prepare 1024 bytes for the output sequence.  The input sequence is
// empty.
boost::asio::streambuf streambuf;
streambuf.prepare(1024);

// prepare() and write to the output sequence, then commit the written
// data to the input sequence.  The API contract has been violated.
std::ostream ostream(&streambuf);
ostream << "1234567890";

// Commit 10 unspecified bytes to the input sequence.  Undefined
// behavior is invoked.
streambuf.commit(10);
```

---

Here is a complete example [demonstrating](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/a0acc1a08f844b2a) using streambuf with annotated comments:

```cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <boost/asio.hpp>

int main()
{
  std::cout << "with streams:" << std::endl;
  {
    boost::asio::streambuf streambuf;

    // prepare() and write to the output sequence, then commit the written
    // data to the input sequence.  The output sequence is empty and
    // input sequence contains "1234567890".
    std::ostream ostream(&streambuf);
    ostream << "1234567890";

    // Read from the input sequence and consume the read data.  The string
    // 'str' contains "1234567890".  The input sequence is empty, the output
    // sequence remains unchanged.
    std::istream istream(&streambuf);
    std::string str;
    istream >> str;
    std::cout << "str = " << str << std::endl;

    // Clear EOF bit.
    istream.clear();

    // prepare() and write to the output sequence, then commit the written
    // data to the input sequence.  The output sequence is empty and
    // input sequence contains "0987654321".
    ostream << "0987654321";

    // Read from the input sequence and consume the read data.  The string
    // 'str' contains "0987654321".  The input sequence is empty, the output
    // sequence remains unchanged.
    istream >> str;
    std::cout << "str = " << str << std::endl;
  }

  std::cout << "with streams and manual operations:" << std::endl;
  {
    boost::asio::streambuf streambuf;

    // prepare() and write to the output sequence, then commit the written
    // data to the input sequence.  The output sequence is empty and
    // input sequence contains "1234567890".
    std::ostream ostream(&streambuf);
    ostream << "1234567890";

    // Copy 10 bytes from the input sequence.  The string `str` contains
    // "1234567890".  The output sequence is empty and the input
    // sequence contains "1234567890".
    auto data = streambuf.data();
    std::string str(boost::asio::buffers_begin(data),
                    boost::asio::buffers_begin(data) + 10);
    std::cout << "str = " << str << std::endl;

    // Consume 10 bytes from the input sequence.  The input sequence is
    // now empty.
    streambuf.consume(10);

    // prepare() and write to the output sequence, then commit the written
    // data to the input sequence.  The output sequence is empty and
    // input sequence contains "0987654321".
    ostream << "0987654321";

    // Copy 10 bytes from the input sequence.  The string `str` contains
    // "0987654321.  The output sequence is empty and the input
    // sequence contains "0987654321".    
    data = streambuf.data();
    str.assign(boost::asio::buffers_begin(data),
               boost::asio::buffers_begin(data) + 10);
    std::cout << "str = " << str << std::endl;

    // Consume 10 bytes from the input sequence.  The input sequence is
    // now empty.
    streambuf.consume(10);
  }
}
```

Output:

```
with streams:
str = 1234567890
str = 0987654321
with streams and manual operations:
str = 1234567890
str = 0987654321
```

For more information on streambuf usage, consider reading [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31992879/1053968) answer.

Comment: Thanks for comment. Finally I looked at boost::asio::async_read_until() implementation and found out that it does streambuf_.commit(bytes_transferred);. So, I should not call commit() in my handler. But in case of using boost::asio::ip::tcp::socket.async_read() my handler should call a commit() to move characters from output sequence to input sequence.

Comment: @drus no you should not. Don't mess with any of those operations. All I ever did was call `buffer.consume(buffer.size() + 1)`, because this is guaranteed to clear the buffer entirely.

Comment: Yes, I switched  to use boost::asio::async_read() and boost::asio::async_read_until() and it works as expected. As I said, both these methods call streambuf.commit().

Comment: For clarification, best practice for `buffer.consume` is to use return value from `boost::asio::async_read*`. E.g. `size_t bytes = boost::asio::async_read_until()` and `buffer.consume(bytes)`

Comment: I wonder what approach is safer and faster clear and reuse existing buffer or recreate the buffer?