# Boost streambuf and write weird behaviour

Tags: c++, boost, boost-asio

I am using streambuf as a storage for serial port communication

```
io_service io;
serial_port sp(io);
sp.open("COM4");
sp.set_option( serial_port_base::baud_rate( 115200 ) );
sp.set_option( serial_port_base::character_size( 8 ) );
sp.set_option( serial_port_base::stop_bits( serial_port_base::stop_bits::one )  );
sp.set_option( serial_port_base::parity( serial_port_base::parity::none ) );
sp.set_option( serial_port_base::flow_control( serial_port_base::flow_control::none )   );
boost::asio::streambuf buffer;
// Fill buffer here
auto size = buffer.size();
std::cout << boost::format("Buffer size: %d") % size << std::endl;
boost::asio::write( sp, buffer );
size = buffer.size();
std::cout << boost::format("Buffer size: %d" ) % size << std::endl;
```

Output:

```
Buffer size: 8
Buffer size: 0
```

Why method `size()` return different values?

Comment: Can you elaborate on why, after you've written out the buffer, you expect it to have a nonzero size?

Comment: @MarkB I am expecting that write operation on serial port or socket will not modify my storage buffer. Usually any write methods do not modify source. Maybe I am interpret sreambuf incorrect?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The [`boost::asio::write()`](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_61_0/doc/html/boost_asio/reference/write/overload5.html) operation consumes from the `streambuf`'s input sequence, and [`streambuf::size()`](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_61_0/doc/html/boost_asio/reference/basic_streambuf/size.html) returns the size of the input sequence.

In this particular case, the `streambuf`'s input sequence contained 8 bytes before the `write()` operation.  The `write()` operation blocks until all data from the input sequence has been written or until an error occurs.  The `write()` operation succeeds, [consuming](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_61_0/doc/html/boost_asio/reference/basic_streambuf/consume.html) 8 bytes from the input sequence, and returns a value to indicate 8 bytes have been transferred.  As all of the input sequence has been consumed, `streambuf.size()` returns 0.

For more information on streambuf usage, consider reading [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31992879/1053968) answer.